# delete operator not functioning as expected in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

In my node.js express application I am retrieving a user from my database

```
const newUser = await User.create({
      username,
      password,
      email,
      avatar,
})
```

but before sending the response with the user object I want to remove the password.

```
delete newUser.password;
return res.status(200).json({ token, user: newUser });
```

but in my response the password is returned.

`console.log(JSON.stringify(newUser))`
returns:

```
{"_id":"11111111","username":"dylan","email":"dylan@email.com","admin":true,"password":"******"}
```

Comment: It should work, from what you're showing us. What do you get if you print the json.stringify of user before you send it?

Comment: You're trying to modify a `const`?

Comment: @Musa in the docs they specifically use a const https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#try_it

Comment: @RaniSharim the password is still there. I'm totally lost on this, it should be simple.

Comment: @DylanL. Can you show the json print (star the password value ofcourse)

Comment: why not use select in query, adding projection in your mongodb query https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/

Comment: I added the console log @RaniSharim

Comment: @VLDCNDN I can, but I'd like to figure out this bug.

Comment: @DylanL. before deleting do a console log foundUser and see after deleting also

Comment: What is `newUser` and `foundUser`?

Comment: as per the answer below, the return from a query is a document not a javascript object, I have to convert it first. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: Why not whitelist the properties you want to send instead of blacklisting the ones you don't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

query return value is document **not javascript object**

- Documents have a `toObject` method which converts the mongoose document into a plain JavaScript object.
- first convert it to object and then use `delete` on each property you want

also with `mongoose` it can done more properly and automatically

```js
User.methods.toJSON = function () {
  const user = this;
  const userObj = user.toObject();
  delete userObj.password;
  return userObj;
};
```

every time you send this document as response it convert to JSON and every time that `JSON.strigify()` is call on a document it call this `toJSON()` method

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can also do

```
delete newUser._doc.password
```